# R converts dates into a wrong format (year to a 5 digit number)

Tags: r

I have loaded a txt dataset into R. A part of it can be seen below:

```
date    rf
1   19620102 0.011
2   19620103 0.011
3   19620104 0.011
4   19620105 0.011
5   19620108 0.011
```

I have tried to convert the dates using the following code:

```
df$date <- format(as.Date(df$date), "%Y-%m-%d")
```

This gives the following results, that are not what I wanted:

```
date    rf
1   55688-01-06 0.011
2   55688-01-07 0.011
3   55688-01-08 0.011
4   55688-01-09 0.011
5   55688-01-12 0.011
```

I wanted to convert the dates into the format as seen below:

```
date    rf
1   1962-01-02 0.011
2   1962-01-03 0.011
3   1962-01-04 0.011
4   1962-01-05 0.011
5   1962-01-08 0.011
```

Does anyone know how I can get the results that I want?

Comment: Try using `anytime`

Comment: Your dates don't have dashes in them, but your `format` string does. Since you don't have dashes in the dates, take them out of the format string. Change `"%Y-%m-%d"`  to `"%Y%m%d"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works

```r
as.Date("19620102", "%Y%m%d")
#> [1] "1962-01-02"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

So just do

```r
as.Date(as.character(df$date), "%Y%m%d")
```

Answer (score 2):

We could also use `ymd` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
ymd(19620102)
#[1] "1962-01-02"
```